# Sorting the array using keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that carries all the routes of my framework. It looks like this

```
$routes=[
    '/[:name]/[:name]/[:name]'   =>['ALL','dynamic','blog']

    '/news'                      =>['ALL','static','news'],

    '/about'                     =>['ALL','static'],

];
```

I want to sort the array based on

- number of slashes(/)
- number of dynamic parameters

in the keys. How will I accomplish it?

Comment: Have you looked at the PHP documentation on how to sort multidimensional arrays?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried uksort() and asort(), but didn't work

Comment: @WEBDEVPR Show us then.

Comment: @WEBDEVPR .. As in your attempts at a solution.

Comment: I used asort($routes) and uksort($routes). But it didn't take care of the number of slashes/dynamic parameter. It sorted based on alphabetical order

Comment: How about sort algorithms based on a user-defined function -- did you look at them?

Comment: @WEBDEVPR As I'm sure you're aware, uksort takes a user-defined function.  Show us the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things are important here. You need to preserve the key to value relationship. That implies that you use array sorting functions like uasort() instead of usort(). The next thing is, that you have to use a user-defined sorting function, which expresses your sorting algo. It describes how you want to sort your routes.

It's also possible to sort by keys: then array_flip() is your friend.

You might use this for starting:

```
<?php

$routes=[
    '/about'                     =>['ALL','static'],
    '/[:name]/[:name]/[:name]'   =>['ALL','dynamic','blog'],
    '/news'                      =>['ALL','static','news'],
];

function sortShortestRoute($a, $b)
{
    return (count($a) < count($b)) ? -1 : 1;
}

function sortStaticBeforeDynamic($a, $b)
{
    if($a[1] === 'static' && $b[1] === 'static') {
        return 1;
    }

    if($a[1] === 'dynamic' && $b[1] === 'dynamic') {
        return -1;
    }

    if ($a[1] === $b[1]) {
        return 0;
    }
}

// first sort
uasort($routes, 'sortStaticBeforeDynamic');

var_dump($routes);

// second sort
uasort($routes, 'sortShortestRoute');

var_dump($routes);
```